# Prevent conversion of ' (apostrophe) to &apos; after saving xml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Each time I  save xml `'` (apostrophe) get converted to `&apos;`.

For example:

```
<entry key="xyz" value="aan('s')">
```

gets converted to

```
<entry key="xyz" value="aan(&apos;s&apos;)">
```

Comment: That's normal. They are equivalent in XML. What's the problem?

Comment: Firstly, it shouldn't be necessary - why is it a problem? Secondly, we can't tell you how to do this unless you tell us what software you are using.